# How will i properly sanitize of wordpress plugin input field?

Tags: wordpress, validation, wordpress-theming, sanitize, sanitization

This is my wordpress plugin code. how will i properly sanitize under this codes

```
  function add_css_validate_setting( $input ) {
        $input['add_css'] = wp_kses( $input['add_css'], array( '\'', '\"', '>', '+' ) );
        return $input;
    }
```

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53970/sanitize-user-entered-css